# Need to re-sign the IPA file with my ad hoc profile

Tags: ios, xcode, html, ipa, ios-provisioning

## I tried to resign one **IPA** file (Project is build under **HTML 5**) using this following scripts,

```
unzip application.ipa

rm -r "Payload/Application.app/_CodeSignature" "Payload/Application.app/CodeResources" 2> /dev/null | true


cp "/Users/playdom/Desktop/BA/Code/Profiles/something.mobileprovision" "Payload/Application.app/embedded.mobileprovision"

/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: something" --resource-rules "Payload/Application.app/ResourceRules.plist" "Payload/Application.app"


zip -qr "Application.test.ipa" Payload
```

=========================

And it changes the sign and I can install the Build at my device. But the problem is whenever I tried to start my application it shows the splash screen and crash!!! I checked the IPA with default Profile (I wanted to change...) and it works ok. That means the problem is in the resign process!!!

I tried check the **Xcode/Organizer/Console** and saw it shows **entitlement** issue!!. I followed the same script and process with other **IPA** (Build under Obj C) it works fine. I don't understand what is the issue? Do I need to change the info.plist, Bundle identifier? I tried that but after that it don't even install!!. Any body has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that's supposed to work. You can't run a build that's signed for the App Store distribution on a device. I always take my App Store builds and re-sign them with a development provisioning profile to test them on a device.